# How should Fragments be shared between Relay containers?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs, relay

In my app, I need to reference the currently signed-in `User` in numerous components at various places in the component hierarchy.

This means I often use a `fragment` like this in my `Relay` containers:

```
fragments: {
 //...

currentUser: () => Relay.QL`
       fragment on User {
           id
           userName
       }
}`
```

To avoid repeating myself, I'm inclined to just `import` this fragment into whatever container I need it in (same for other ubiquitous fragments, as well). The Relay docs call this `inline fragments`:

```
var userFrag =  () => Relay.QL`
       fragment on User {
           id
           userName
       }`
```

However, [the Relay docs have this warning](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/api-reference-relay-ql.html):

> Note that it is highly recommended that Relay.Containers define their
>   own fragments and avoid sharing inline var fragment = Relay.QL...
>   values between containers or files. If you find yourself wanting to
>   share inline fragments, it's likely a sign that it's time to refactor
>   and introduce a new container.

This confuses me for a few reasons:

1. I can't reason why it's ill-advised to share fragments in the fashion I've described above.
2. How would I go about 'introducing a new container' to alleviate this repetition? Do they mean wrapping any `Component` that needs `User` in another dedicated `Relay` container?  This seems counterintuitive and like too much boilerplate.

Is there a less frowned-upon way to share fragments, then? Or am I misreading the docs' admonition?

Comment: I find it weird too. But is sharing the inline fragment needed ?

Comment: I think they advise against it because the Container should fetch exactly which data the Component uses. When you will change the Component to display more fields, you will add the fields to the colocated fragment. To be honest, myself I'm using Relay in production and never use inline fragment. Colocation of the fragments and the Components is enough.

Comment: I agree it's not terrible to work around--what's surprising is that it's specifically warned against.  I wish the docs' explanation of 'refactor and introduce a new container' was a little more clear to me, but as it stands, the idea that I could "introduce a new container" to solve this problem makes me think I'm missing an important point about `Relay` design patterns, as I have no idea what kind of container I could introduce to solve this.

Comment: but i guess it makes sense if their intent is to have data declared and enumerated within the container.  Fragmenting moves the actual field names to another file, which, while it's still co-location from the app architecture point of view, is effectively not co-location for, say, a dev reading the `.js` file.

Comment: I think the doc is just not clear here, I don't see what they can mean too :smile:

Comment: Anyways I don't think it's too bad to use inline fragments :)

Comment: Ad.1. I would guess the creator suggest that containers should depend only on other containers by including their fragments in straight way and there's no place for any other layer of abstraction like  *library* of fragments. Ad.2. You may seem right with this wrapping. This does not look like best architecture for your case, but again, I would guess that's what they suggest.

Comment: One more thing - is it for you such pain to repeat those two fields `id, userName`? If you have more complicated case, maybe you should follow that way of separating another container? Or if you now go into dozens of writing this fields cread containers that would represent most common cases and limit repeating to just couple?